# Setuid Perl script works on Solaris, but not Linux

Tags: linux, perl, solaris

OK, this is weird. But in the process of trying to reproduce an issue for someone (where this became a potential moot point), I found this interesting oddity... Taking this stupid-simple perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use POSIX;

$ENV{"PATH"} = "/usr/bin";
print "Effective:" . $> . "\n";
print "Actual   :" . $< . "\n";
print "geteuid():" . geteuid() . "\n";
```

If I create this script as (for example) root, set it to 4755 permissions, I get this on Solaris 11.4 (Perl 5.22.1) and Solaris 10.3 (Perl 5.16.1):

```
Effective:0
Actual   :100
geteuid():0
```

The SAME exact script, run on the same or later Perl versions, but on Linux (RHEL 7.7, Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 20.04, RHEL 6.10) gives me:

```
Effective:100
Actual   :100
geteuid():100
```

If I create a suid executable on Linux that runs this script, I get the expected 0/100/0 output.

On the RHEL 6.10 host, it also has Perl 5.8.4 on it, and that perl, once suidperl is installed, also gives me 0/100/0 as expected.

Any idea why this works on Solaris and not Linux? Platform specific quirks are a little annoying when you're dealing with migration/upgrade issues...

Comment: Does [Allow setuid on shell scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts) help?

Comment: @TedLyngmo not so much because it's actually the issue here. Perl is supposed to support this, but now it's "works on some platforms, doesn't work on others where it used to..."

Comment: Have you read [`perlsec`: Shebang Race Condition](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Shebang-Race-Condition) too?

Comment: I read both, but again, it doesn't answer the fundamental question of "Why does PERL work on *this* platfrom and not *that* one?" I suspect that the answer to this one is something along the lines of "some Linux Perl maintainer didn't like this and killed it" but I can't prove or disprove that hypothesis.

Comment: If we were talking Windows/Unix, or Unix/Cygwin, or Unix/Mingw, that would be a different issue. Here we're comparing Solaris 10/11 and multiple Linux versions. It seems interesting that the dichotomy is so abrupt...

Comment: Different platforms (and versions of platforms) have different security measures I guess. Not even two Linuxes are alike since you can tweak security settings. Are all your tested perl versions compiled with `SETUID_SCRIPTS_ARE_SECURE_NOW` ( `perl -V | grep SETUID_SCRIPTS_ARE_SECURE_NOW`) as mentioned in `perlsec`? Even if you use the same version on two different platforms, that option will determine if you can do what you hope to do in newer perl versions if I read it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If portability is an issue, it's not safe to assume that a Unix-like platform will respect the setuid flag on scripts. That's not an issue with Perl, or any other interpreter -- limitations like this are backed into the platform at a pretty deep level. Many people are concerned -- with good reason -- that allowed setuid scripts creates security weaknesses.

The standard solution -- as you've already figured out -- is to call the script from a binary that has the setuid flag set.